# The entity or complex type '' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query, three table outer join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I see some related questions on stack, but not sure how to still solve it for my problem as I'm doing a three table left outer join. `RoleUser` and `Role` are an entity object

```
var query = from u in Context.Users
            join ru in Context.RoleUsers on u.Id equals ru.UserId into plv
            from x in plv.DefaultIfEmpty(new RoleUser())
            join r in Context.Roles on x.RoleId equals r.Id into pii
            from y in pii.DefaultIfEmpty(new Role())
            orderby u.Id, y.Id
            select new UserWithRole() { Id = u.Id, User = u, Role = y };
```

Comment: On which type do you get it? `UserWithRole` `RoleUser` or `Role`

Comment: Use parametrless `DefaultIfEmpty()`. The overload you are using is not supported.

Comment: @IvanStoev  when the RoleUser or Role is values are empty I get a null reference error

Comment: Well, that's a problem of the code that is using the query result, not the query. Do you need to keep the query `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` would work?

Comment: @IvanStoev I think it can be IEnumerable<T>, but how would we convert that to an IEnumerable result,

Answer (score 1):

As the error explains you cannot create in a linq query they mapped types (`RoleUser` and `Role`). Instead use the `DefaultIfEmpty()`. Something along the following:

```
var roles = from ru in Context.RoleUsers 
            join r in Context.Roles on ru.RoleId equals r.Id
            select new { ru.UserId, role = r };

var query = from u in Context.Users
            join r in roles on u.Id equals r.UserId into plv
            from x in plv.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new UserWithRole() { Id = u.Id, User = u, Role = x.role };
```

However I'd suggest look into navigation properties - that way you will not have to construct the joins and work with it as if it is "normal" objects.

Comment: @Mo Ahmad - Does the following give you a null reference?

Comment: actually I could not get this to compile  'Cannot implicitly convert type '<anonymous type: int UserId, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Server.Database.Role> role>' to 'Server.Database.Role''

Comment: @MoAhmad - true - I had a mistake - how about now?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `DefaultIfEmpty(new RoleUser())` and `DefaultIfEmpty(new Role())` calls, because EF cannot translate creation of a constant entity object to SQL.

So you need to use the parameterless overload of `DefaultIfEmpty()` and deal with `null` objects in the materialized query result.

If you don't need a `IQueryable<T>` result, you can use intermediate anonymous type projection, which to LINQ to Objects context by using `AsEnumerable()` and do the final desired projection:

```
var query = (from u in Context.Users
             join ru in Context.RoleUsers on u.Id equals ru.UserId into userRoles
             from ru in userRoles.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join r in Context.Roles on ru.RoleId equals r.Id into roles
             from r in roles.DefaultIfEmpty()
             orderby u.Id, r.Id
             select new { User = u, Role = r }
            )
            .AsEnumerable() // db query ends here
            .Select(x => new UserWithRole
            {
                Id = x.User.Id,
                User = x.User,
                Role = x.Role ?? new Role() // now this is supported
            });
```

Comment: That seems to work on most scenarios, but I dont see why this query is failing on the case where the user, has no role and no roleuser...it should still return a user, but it returns null.